# How do I create an Android tab bar with Bootstrap for web pages?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, web

How do I create an Android tab bar (Example tab bar WhatsApp application) with Bootstrap for web pages?
Thanks for your answer

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this? As SO is not free coding platform. People here people if OP has tried anything in that direction. Please show us the effort.

Comment: I think you want bootstrap navbar if yes then check the following link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap `nav` component with `justified` option for equal widths nav items similar to the tab bar in android.

Example code (from [Bootstrap 4.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/#fill-and-justify) docs):

```
<nav class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
  <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Much longer nav link</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
</nav>
```